# post slug and category in same url endpoint

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

i want to develop a blog application. i want to category and post same url in same endpoint

**example:**
when i visit **https://xyzblog.com/technology**  then redirect category page
and when i visit **https://xyzblog.com/how-to-make-someting** then show post

note: We are using **laravel** for api development and **react** for frontend development. please suggest how can we design our system to maintain best practices

thank you

try:

post_table

```
| ID       | Content  | title                  | cat_id   | slug                |
| -------- | --------   ---------------------- | -------- |--------             |
| 1        | content  | how-to-make-something  |  3       |how-to-make-xyz      |
| 3        | content  | how-to-make-xyz        |  5       |how-to-make-something|
```

category_table

```
| ID       | Name        |
| -------- | --------    |
|   1      | technology  |
|   2      | traveling   |
```

slug_table

```
| id       | slug                   | slug_type  |  
| -------- | --------               |--------    |
| 1        | technology             | category   |
| 2        | how-to-make-something  | post       |
| 2        | how-to-make-xyz        | post       |
```

when slug type category then redirect category page with category wise posts
and when slug_type post then redirect post detail page with posts

this is our thinking please suggest me the best system design concept.

Comment: I suppose best practice would rather _not_ be what you are trying to do here, but to use a URL pattern that makes these two different types discernible from each other on that level already. You do not want to _redirect_ the request elsewhere, but only to _rewrite_ it internally, so that the correct controller action will process it. If you don't make the two types discernible by URL - then you can only rewrite both to the _same_ target, and then go look the slug up in the database in that place - only after that will you know, which type it actually is.

Comment: what happens when two posts exist with the same `technology` category?

Comment: when two post exist in same technology category  then technology page show two post @krisgjika

Comment: the category page does not redirect than. the proper system design would be to have a `pages/{slug}` and a `categories/{slug}` routes.

Comment: how do wordpress site can show category page when i visit www.example.com/{category_name} and when i visit www.example.com/{post_slug} then show post details page how can i do this ?? @krisgjika

Comment: @AbdullahalNoman probably bc wordpress has only pages, your "category" in wordpress is the same as any other page. I guess you can create a route `/{slug}` but careful not to have a slug like `users` if you want to also have a route `/users`

Comment: What happens when you have a post with the slug "technology"? I mean a post with a slug, same as a category slug.

Comment: @AbdullahalNoman Don't expect what happens in `WordPress` to happen similarly in `Laravel`